# Scala / Spark: how to define serializable case classes (non-REPL)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Scala newbie here.
I wrote a draft of a Spark job in a Zeppelin notebook. I used Datasets api, so to make my case classes properly serialize when doing `ds.map(s => MyCaseClass(...))` I defined my case classes **in a separate notebook cell**. Otherwise, it wouldn't work.

Now I'm writing an actual job to run it in Apache Airflow.
Main file looks like this:

```
class MainObj {
   private val spark = SparkSession.builder()...getOrCreate()       
   import spark.implicits._

   case class MyCaseClass(...)

   def run() {       
      spark.read
      ...
      .map(s => MyCaseClass(...))
      ...
   }
}

object MainObj {
   def apply(arguments: Arguments, sparkConf: Traversable[(String, String)]) = 
      new MainObj(arguments, sparkConf)

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      MainObj(...).run()
   }
}
```

In this case, I get:

> Unable to generate an encoder for inner class MainObj$MyCaseClass without access to the scope that this class was defined in.

If I add `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.OuterScopes.addOuterScope(this)` inside or before `run()`, I get:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MainObj
>   Serialization stack: object not serializable (class: MainObj, value: MainObj@2f11d889)

I also tried moving case classes to a separate file (doesn't work) or inside `run()` (doesn't even compile).

Very frustrated by this problem... Can anyone help, or at least point me to a place that explains the relation between `case classes`, `spark.implicits` and `scopes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your case classes at the root level, not in a Class / Object.

Can you try with the following structure ?

```
case class MyCaseClass(...)

class MainObj {
   private val spark = SparkSession.builder()...getOrCreate()       
   import spark.implicits._

   def run() {       
      spark.read
      ...
      .map(s => MyCaseClass(...))
      ...
   }
}

object MainObj {
   def apply(arguments: Arguments, sparkConf: Traversable[(String, String)]) = 
      new MainObj(arguments, sparkConf)

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      MainObj(...).run()
   }
}
```

Comment: You're right! Although I actually tried this. I found out that my issue had a different root cause which I did not include in the original question, so I'm accepting your answer as correct (for the question I asked).

Answer (score 0):

I left out a very important piece of code when writing the question.

**Actually**, my broken code looked like this:

```
class MainObj {
   private val spark = SparkSession.builder()...getOrCreate()       
   import spark.implicits._

   case class MyCaseClass(...)

   // This is what I left out
   def someFunction() { 
      ...
   }

   def run() {       
      spark.read
      ...
      .map(s => { ...someFunction() ... }) // and this
      .map(s => MyCaseClass(...))
      ...
   }
}

object MainObj {
   def apply(arguments: Arguments, sparkConf: Traversable[(String, String)]) = 
      new MainObj(arguments, sparkConf)

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      MainObj(...).run()
   }
}
```

And this is how a working code looks like:

```
// FIXED: moved case class to the root scope
case class MyCaseClass(...)

class MainObj {
   private val spark = SparkSession.builder()...getOrCreate()       
   import spark.implicits._                  

   def run() {       
      spark.read
      ...
      .map(s => { ... MainObj.someFunction() ... }) // FIXED
      .map(s => MyCaseClass(...))
      ...
   }
}

object MainObj {
   // FIXED: moved function to a companion object; 
   // now calling it inside map(...) does not trigger serialization 
   // of MainObj object, it works like a static method call in Java
   def someFunction() {}

   def apply(arguments: Arguments, sparkConf: Traversable[(String, String)]) = 
      new MainObj(arguments, sparkConf)

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      MainObj(...).run()
   }
}
```